# Why do I have to specify my own class when using super(), and is there a way to get around it?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

When using Python's `super()` to do method chaining, you have to explicitly specify your own class, for example:

```
class MyDecorator(Decorator):
    def decorate(self):
        super(MyDecorator, self).decorate()
```

I have to specify the name of my class `MyDecorator` as an argument to `super()`. This is not DRY. When I rename my class now I will have to rename it twice. Why is this implemented this way? And is there a way to weasel out of having to write the name of the class twice(or more)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BDFL agrees. See [PEP 3135 - New Super](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) for Python 3.0 (and [Pep 367 - New Super](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0367/) for Python 2.6).

Answer (score 11):

In Python 3.0, you can use `super()` which is equivalent to `super(ThisClass, self)`.

Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#super). Code sample from the documentation:

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super().method(arg)    
        # This does the same thing as: super(C, self).method(arg)
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer is wrong, try:

```
def _super(cls):
    setattr(cls, '_super', lambda self: super(cls, self))
    return cls

class A(object):
    def f(self):
        print 'A.f'

@_super
class B(A):
    def f(self):
        self._super().f()

@_super
class C(B):
    def f(self):
        self._super().f()

C().f() # maximum recursion error
```

---

In Python 2 there is a way using decorator:

```
def _super(cls):
    setattr(cls, '_super', lambda self: super(cls, self))
    return cls

class A(object):
    def f(self):
        print 'A.f'

@_super
class B(A):
    def f(self):
        self._super().f()

B().f() # >>> A.f
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also avoid writing a concrete class name in older versions of python by using

```
def __init__(self):
    super(self.__class__, self)
    ...
```

Comment: No, that won't work because __class__ will give you the most specific subclass for the instance, not necessarily the one in the context of the class we are writing.

Comment: I feel it's unfair to the author to down-vote this answer. This answer makes a naive but common misconception. It deserves stating here, along with toby's explanation of why this fails to work. There's worth in reporting methods which DON'T work, too.