# Why it is compulsory to give classname while using super() in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I have to specify my own class when using super(), and is there a way to get around it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466611/why-do-i-have-to-specify-my-own-class-when-using-super-and-is-there-a-way-to)

I was reading this book - `"Core Python Programming"`, and I really found it very nice I would say. But I got confused at a point while I was studying the topic Inheritance..

The book somewhere said that- we can use `super()` to invoke `super class method` which will find the base class method for us and also we don't need to pass `self` explicitly, like we do without super..

Here's the sample code: -

```
# Invoking super class method without super() .. Need to pass `self` as argument
class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        Parent.foo(self)

# Invoking with super().
# No need to pass `self` as argument to foo()
class Child(Parent1, Parent2):
    def foo(self):
        super(Child, self).foo()
        print 'Hi, I am Child-foo()'
```

My Question is -  why we have to pass the `classname` to `super()` call.. As the classname can be inferred from the class from which super is invoked..

So, since super() is invoked from 
`class Child`, classname should be implicit there.. So why do we need that??

*EDIT: - Giving `Child` as a parameter to super() doesn't make sense, because it doesn't give any information.. We could have used `super(self)`.. And the method would have been searched in the super classes in the order they are given inside parenthesis..

Comment: in Python 3 you could use just `super()`. [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: OOPs. can't access that link in office.. :( Will see it back home..

Comment: you can do `super().__init__()` in python 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By providing the class name as first argument you provide redundant information. Yes. That's a bit stupid* and that's why the behavior of `super` is changed in Python 3 to:

```
super().__init__()
```

*With my answer I actually contradict the answer by John Carter. Only one of us is right, of course. I don't want to offend him and others and I am happy to see a meaningful example where `super(C, self).method(arg)` is not actually used within class `C` :-).

Comment: Thanks Jan... I was using Python 2.7. Quite a different behaviour it has..

Comment: You're right Jan.  I withdraw my initial answer without offence.

Comment: you can do `super().__init__()` in python 3. :)